# CD-related tags

Tags: discussion, support, retag-request, tag-synonym-request

Why do we have both [compact-disc](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/compact-disc) and [cd-rom](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/cd-rom)?

UPDATE: Please vote on options below.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are 5x as many tagged  compact-disk as cd-rom, so I'm just going to merge cd-rom into compact-disk. I'll go through and manually retag the ones which mean cd-rom as in the device to add [optical-drive](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/optical-drive).

Comment: Could you add a synonym so that we won’t have more cdrom-related questions in the [tag:cd] tag?

Comment: That was done automatically as part of the merging process.

Answer (score 4):

Make [cd-rom](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/cd-rom) a synonym of [compact-disc](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/compact-disc).

Comment: +1 Going against the grain here. Technically, I think that this is the correct relation.

Answer (score -2):

Make [compact-disc](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/compact-disc) a synonym of [cd-rom](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/cd-rom).